# Temp. table in an android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a phone app. I would like to give the call waiting feature. Let us assume the call waiting is enabled.

Now I get a new call to my phone with number +1-646 123 4564. I answer the call now I get one more call while I am talking to the first caller - The screen shows the number +1-646 321 4568 I don't answer the second caller. The second caller disconnects. Now I would like to display first caller number which is +1-646 123 4564

How to store the first caller number temp. without using a database. Is this possible? if so how? or is there any temp. database that can get created and gets deleted.

The problem I am facing is that the activity gets refreshed every time I receive a call . Hence can't put them in a variable.

**Update:**

Tried Shared Preference

For saving the number

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("incomingnumbersp", incomingnumber);
    editor.commit();
```

For retrieving the number:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) 
    {
      incomingnumber = prefs.getString("incomingnumbers", "1234567891");
    }
```

This doesn't get into the if condition as it is always null.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the number using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

#### For saving the number

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("incomingnumbersp", incomingnumber);
editor.commit();
```

#### For retrieving the number

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE, 0);
String incomingnumber = settings.getString("incomingnumbersp", "1234567891");
```

Comment: Yeah. I tried it but didn't work.. Please check my question for the update.

Comment: You almost have it.  Your code for retrieving the number is incorrect.  I will update my answer to include sample code.